# Como poner los datos de una consulta y ponerlas en una nueva tabla?

Tags: sql-server

Si podrian ayudarme en como podría hacer, que en cualquier consulta que haga, pueda hacer que esa información ya hecha ponerla en una tabla totalmente nueva.

Si alguien puede responderme seria un gran favor, hasta con enviarme un ejemplo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene un parecido con la anterior, se te pidio que des mas detalles ya que no estas siendo muy claro por favor trata de editar tu pregunta lo mas que puedas para poder ayudarte, informacion de tus tablas y lo que haz intendado es de gran ayudada.... Saludos

Comment: Amigo te repito no eres muy claro con lo que pides, te pido que formules de lo mas claro tu pregunta para poder ayudarte... saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server tiene soporte para dos instrucciones que pueden ayudarte.

## select/into

Esta requiere que NO exista la tabla de destino, sino que sea totalmente nueva. Esta nueva tabla tomará su estructura, es decir, nombres de campos, tipos de dato y otros atributos de acuerdo a los resultados de la consulta.

Por ejemplo, la sentencia:

```
select tabla1.campo1, tabla2.campo2
  into miTablaNueva
  from tabla1 
       inner join tabla2 on tabla2.campo1 = tabla1.campo1
 where tabla1.otroCampo = 'Mi condición';
```

Creará una nueva tabla llamada `miTablaNueva` que tendrá dos campos, `campo1` y `campo2`, cada uno con el tipo de dato correspondiente a los campos de origen en `tabla1` y `tabla2`.

## insert/select

En este caso, la tabla de destino ya debe existir en la base de datos. Esta tabla puede tener datos, al final, la sentencia es un `insert` *normal*, que adiciona nuevas filas a las ya existentes.

Por ejemplo la sentencia:

```
insert into miTablaExistente (campo1, campo2)
select tabla1.campo1, tabla2.campo2
  from tabla1 
       inner join tabla2 on tabla2.campo1 = tabla1.campo1
 where tabla1.otroCampo = 'Mi otra condición';
```

Añadirá a `miTablaExistente` tantas filas como devuelva la consulta `select`.

Tal como en otros *inserts*, se puede omitir la lista de campos de la clausula `into`, siempre que la consulta devuelva el mismo número de campos que tiene la tabla de destino, y que los tipos de dato coincidan o puedan convertirse automáticamente en el orden en que aparecen en dicha tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias y ya pude encontrar otra formas. Pero de verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: Es un gusto ser de ayuda, un saludo ;)